# Searching within AlertDialog

Tags: android, search, dialog

I have an alert dialog which lists around 100 cities. Is there a way to search within it? Or maybe autocomplete?

[image]

I want to add a textbox which will filter the list according to what I type.

EDIT: I'm very SORRY. What I meant was that I wanted to FILTER the above list based on what I type in a textbox. For example if I type 'D', I should get only Dhaka..

Comment: @RohithNandkumar This only works if your objects are of String. Any other work around for other objects of custom classes we wrote?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok I finally managed to do it using a custom Dialog.

citylistview.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="200dip" 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center">
    <EditText android:id="@+id/EditBox" 
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="180dip"
        android:gravity="left">
    </EditText> 
    <ListView android:id="@+id/List"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice">
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

CityListDialog.java

```
public class CityListDialog extends Dialog implements OnClickListener {

private ListView list;
private EditText filterText = null;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = null;
private static final String TAG = "CityList";

public CityListDialog(Context context, String[] cityList) {
    super(context);

    /** Design the dialog in main.xml file */
    setContentView(R.layout.citylistview);
    this.setTitle("Select City");
    filterText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditBox);
    filterText.addTextChangedListener(filterTextWatcher);
    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.List);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, cityList);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Selected Item is = "+list.getItemAtPosition(position));
        }
    });
}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

}
private TextWatcher filterTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {
    }

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
            int count) {
        adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
    }
};
@Override
public void onStop(){
    filterText.removeTextChangedListener(filterTextWatcher);
}}
```

This is the results I get when I call the dialog. Thanks everyone. [image]

Comment: This works, but how should I make the Dialog close automatically once an item is selected? (Currently, it only closes for me if I tap outside of the Dialog) Calling `onBackPressed()` works, but is this a good way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

alert dialog which list around 100 cities? what this exactly means to?

yes for search we can use autocomplete

```
AutoCompleteTextView Auto=new AutoCompleteTextView(this);
ArrayAdapter<String> arrAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,name);
Auto.setAdapter(arrAdapter);
```

are you exactly meaning this?

Comment: With "alert dialog which list around 100 cities", I mean the above screenshot. How you get the idea. When i type in the text box, I want to filter the list accordingly.

Comment: s if u use autocomplete textbox u will be able to filter the items...which show the result in its own list view. but if u want your own listview to change dynamically,i think MGS answer will support you

Answer (score 1):

if suppose  u have list of items in array you need to set it into list,and then use EditText for searching,you can implement it by
by using EditText  addTextChangedListener(this) action listener by implementing three method and do what u need

here the sample code of this implementaion has follows

```
@Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        try{
        text = textView.getText().toString();
        string1 = text.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + text.substring(1);
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.v("Text_Hereeeee++++++++++++++++++++++++++++e","NULL"+Integer.toString(a.length));


//          wv.setVisibility(View.GONE);    
            lv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Bru_Maps.this,R.layout.listitem, a); 
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
            lv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            empty_text=2;
            temp_VALUE1=null;
            VALUE1=a;

        }
        if(empty_text==1){
        Log.v("Text from ",text);
        Set <String> has_set = new TreeSet<String>(search_List);
        if(string1!=null)
        {
            Log.v("string1_for New array",string1);
            for(int i=0;i<VALUE1.length;i++)
            {
                String a = string1;

            if(VALUE1[i].startsWith(a))
            {
//               Log.v("NoDuplicate New array","null");
                 has_set.add(VALUE1[i]);


              }
            else{
                continue;
            }
            }

        }
        Log.v("Text_Her********************e","NULL"+Integer.toString(VALUE1.length));
           carArray = new String[has_set.size()];

           has_set.toArray(carArray);

            temp_VALUE1=carArray;
            lv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Bru_Maps.this,R.layout.listitem, temp_VALUE1); 
            Log.v("Adapter_Get_count",Integer.toString(adapter.getCount()));
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
            lv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {
        Log.v("beforeTextChanged",s.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        Log.v("onTextChanged",s.toString());
        empty_text=1;

    }
```

here i just managing two arrays, one is original from that is a and another one is sorted array temp_VALUE1 set in adapter.

Comment: I dont know, but Im not sure this is exactly what I want.. I dont think I made it clear enough :(

Answer (score 1):

These are just ideas, but may be you can use them.

- What if you'll make an custom dialog with a custom design.
- Then you can have your edit field for filtering.
- Every time you type a new letter you should reset your list adapter.

Mur

Ps.
If you have your cities in DB, you can also use cursor-adapter

**UPD:**

[Here is an example](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomDialog) for using usual layouts also in custom dialogs. Hence you can also put a listview. In your case it would be something like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <EditText
    android:id="@+id/filter"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
 <ListView android:id="@+id/ListView01"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Yes I was thinking of doing that. But Im relatively new to this and was trying to figure out how to put a list in the custom view :) any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

@rohith 
I thought you migh tlike to know that still, nearly two years later,
your answer is helping people learn!

I was able to get your solution to work with a cursor, though it's probably not up to snuff.

here it is:

```
 public class SearchableActivity extends Dialog implements OnClickListener 
 {

    CursorAdapter mAdapter;

    ListView countryListView;
    private EditText filterText = null;
    Context context;

    public SearchableActivity(Context context) 
    {
        super(context);
        setContentView(R.layout.countrysearch);

        String[] from;
        int[] to;           

            /*
             *dbConnector and cursor 
             *are close() before entering class
             */

            dbConnector.open();

        this.setTitle("Pick a Country");

        filterText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditBox);
        filterText.addTextChangedListener(filterTextWatcher);
        filterText.requestFocus();

        countryListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.List);

        cursor = dbConnector.getAllCountries("simpletable");

        from = new String[] { "country" };
        to = new int[] { android.R.id.text1 };

        mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(context,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, cursor, from, to);

        countryListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        countryListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3)
            {
                cursor.close();
                dbConnector.close();

                //send the data out
                finishSearch(arg3);

            }

        });
    }


    @Override
    public void onStop(){
        filterText.removeTextChangedListener(filterTextWatcher);
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void doMySearch(String s)
    {
            // this is a LIKE search on DB
        cursor = dbConnector.getSearch(s);
        mAdapter.changeCursor(cursor);

    }


    private TextWatcher filterTextWatcher = new TextWatcher()
    {

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
        {
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after)
        {
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count)
        {
            doMySearch(s.toString());
        }
    };

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear that :) thanks for the solution.. always good to know the alternatives :D